# Trying to display a title based on the url in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

So i'm putting together a simple php page which will display different content based on what url is put in. For some reason it seems to make it through the whole if statement without doing anything.

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('offer', $_GET)) {
        if( $_GET == "ncp" ){
            $title = 'Exclusive Offer from NCP';
        } elseif($_GET == "rt") {
            $title = 'Exclusive Offer from RT';
        } elseif($_GET == "oo") {
            $title = 'Exclusive Offer from OO';
        }
    } else {
        $title = 'Check Out These Exclusive Offers!';
    }
    $title = strip_tags($title);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Read about `$_GET` variable in manual (tip: it's array).

Comment: Why are you adding the `strip_tags` if you are setting it yourself? And what `if` statement are you talking about? The overall or another?

Comment: @ElonThan I deleted my comment (where is `offer` array), so questions like this, again... "opens up another can of worms". I should be going fishing today actually.

Comment: `$_GET` is an array. you're comparing that array directly against strings. That's a no-no.

Comment: @putvande I wasn't setting it myself at first, just never removed it.

Comment: @MarcB Is there a better way to detect if there is a string?

Comment: @OneEightLeft: see joren's answer below.

Comment: @OneEightLeft Is your problem solved already? If so, please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `$_GET['offer'] == "foo"` instead of `$_GET == "foo"`

Better yet, use strict comparison in the future to make sure you are comparing the same types (in this case strings): `===`. This is because PHP has the tendency to cast types around, which can be both useful and annoying (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
$foo = "0";  // $foo is string (ASCII 48)
$foo += 2;   // $foo is now an integer (2)
$foo = $foo + 1.3;  // $foo is now a float (3.3)
$foo = 5 + "10 Little Piggies"; // $foo is integer (15)
$foo = 5 + "10 Small Pigs";     // $foo is integer (15)
```

`$_GET`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

comparison operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it Try this
I always make it a point to clean any variable passed via $_POST, $_GET or any external source thats why I use filter_var.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['offer'])) {     
      //lets sanitize $_GET['offer'] if it exist since its passed via url
      $offer = filter_var($_GET['offer'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
      $offer = NULL;
    }

    switch ($offer) {
    case 'ncp':
      $title = 'Exclusive Offer from NCP';
    break;
    case 'rt':
      $title = 'Exclusive Offer from RT';
    break;
    case 'oo':
      $title = 'Exclusive Offer from OO';
    break;
    default:
      $title = 'Check Out These Exclusive Offers!';
    break;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use $_GET in php. Give it a try

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['offer'])){
    if( $_GET['offer'] == "ncp" ){
    $title = 'Exclusive Offer from NCP';
    }
    elseif( $_GET['offer'] == "rt" ){
    $title = 'Exclusive Offer from RT';
    }
    elseif( $_GET['offer'] == "oo" ){
    $title = 'Exclusive Offer from OO';
    }
} 
else {
    $title = 'Check Out These Exclusive Offers!';
}
$title = strip_tags($title);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
```